# return multiple queries from backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, redux

Straight forward: I have a backend with multiple routes.

Is it possible to return multiple queries from one route, e.g.:

```
router.get("/test/:id", (req, res) => {
  example.find({test: req.params.id})
    .then(data => res.json(data.map(moreData => moreData.serialize()))

  differentExample.find({something: req.params.id})
    .then(data => res.json(data.map(moreData => moreData.serialize()))
})
```

And then have both finds/results in the front-end:

```
.then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
        return Promise.reject(res.statusText);
    }
    return res.json();
})
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

I found that if I user `Promise.all()` I use the result of the first query for the query parameters of the second. The above is just my thought process. It doesn't work like this and I am missing the piece that makes it happen (if it's possible)

Answer (score 0):

You can't send multiple responses using HTTP. HTTP requests to responses are 1:1 so when a request is sent you will ALWAYS expect only one response. Anything else and it would get quickly messy. So, how to send multiple sets of data?

You could do something like this:

```
router.get("/test/:id", (req, res) => {
  let result = {}
  example.find({test: req.params.id})
    .then(data => {
        result['partOne'] = data.map(moreData => moreData.serialize())
        return differentExample.find({something: req.params.id})
    }).then(data => {
        result['partTwo'] = data.map(moreData => moreData.serialize())
        res.json(result)
    })
}
```

Note: I haven't tested any of this code. But in essence, do both requests, and once you have the result of both requests you can return the result. If the requests don't depend on each other, you could use something like this using `Promise.all` as you mentioned:

```
Promise.all(
    example.find({test: req.params.id}, 
    differentExample.find({something: req.params.id})
).then(result => {
    res.json(result);
})
```

Comment: In case you need, since MongoDB 4.0 you can also use transactions. Then either both queries will work or both can be rolled back.